# IntelliJ deletes properties at hotdeploy

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea

I am developing a Java webapp with IntelliJ on a tomcat server. I have a properties file for i.e. the database connection:

```
jdbc.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url = localhost
jdbc.database = testdb
jdbc.login = postgres
jdbc.password = 1234
```

If i build the project everything works fine. If i change a .jsp and perform 'Update Resources' the properties get lost from the pages context and so does the database connection.

I just learned that this project is based on the Struts frameword. (It's an existing project, where I came new into). The properties file is in a src/main/config folder. There is a database.xml file for the properties:

```
<dict>
<key>driver</key>
<string>${jdbc.driver}</string>
<key>url</key>
<string>jdbc:postgresql://${jdbc.url}/${jdbc.database}</string>
<key>user</key>
<string>${jdbc.login}</string>
<key>password</key>
<string>${jdbc.password}</string>
</dict>
```

When I redeploy I get a message like:

```
Dez 10, 2015 9:43:40 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader modified
SCHWERWIEGEND:     Resource '/WEB-INF/classes/resources/application.properties' is missing
Dez 10, 2015 9:43:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMATION: Reloading Context with name [/project] has started
Dez 10, 2015 9:43:40 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SCHWERWIEGEND: The web application [/project] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Can you give me a hint which setting i have to use that the properties stay in the context?

Comment: where's that properties file located ? how is it loaded ? what's the exception you get after redeploy ?